# Https support in citrus framework

Tags: citrus-framework

Am trying to do integration testing for one of my mule project which uses soap web service. Am using citrus framework to do it.

Not able to provide https url in my testcase in endpoint tag.Am getting the error as " Unable to create endpoint component with name 'https'" I tried with http it shows 'connection timeout'
My sandbox link is configured with secured http. How do I achieve this?

```
INFO  2016-10-13 17:33:00,037 [main] org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2ba45490: startup date [Thu Oct 13 17:33:00 IST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@38cee291
INFO  2016-10-13 17:33:00,284 [main] com.consol.citrus.actions.EchoAction: TODO: Code the test Submit_Supplier_Invoice
INFO  2016-10-13 17:33:00,286 [main] com.consol.citrus.Citrus:
ERROR 2016-10-13 17:33:00,287 [main] com.consol.citrus.Citrus: TEST FAILED Submit_Supplier_Invoice  Nested exception is:
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: Unable to create endpoint component with name 'https'
        at com.consol.citrus.endpoint.DefaultEndpointFactory.create(DefaultEndpointFactory.java:113) ~[citrus-core-2.6.jar:?]
        at com.consol.citrus.actions.SendMessageAction.getOrCreateEndpoint(SendMessageAction.java:142) ~[citrus-core-2.6.jar:?]
        at com.consol.citrus.actions.SendMessageAction.isDisabled(SendMessageAction.java:112) ~[citrus-core-2.6.jar:?]
        at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.executeAction(TestCase.java:210) ~[citrus-core-2.6.jar:?]
        at com.consol.citrus.TestCase.doExecute(TestCase.java:142) ~[citrus-core-2.6.jar:?]
        at com.consol.citrus.actions.AbstractTestAction.execute(AbstractTestAction.java:42) ~[citrus-core-2.6.jar:?]
        at com.consol.citrus.Citrus.run(Citrus.java:254) ~[citrus-core-2.6.jar:?]
        at com.consol.citrus.testng.AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.run(AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.java:104) ~[citrus-core-2.6.jar:?]
        at com.consol.citrus.testng.AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.run(AbstractTestNGCitrusTest.java:70) ~[citrus-core-2.6.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:209) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064) ~[testng-6.9.10.jar:?]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:132) ~[surefire-testng-2.19.jar:2.19]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:134) ~[surefire-testng-2.19.jar:2.19]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:118) ~[surefire-testng-2.19.jar:2.19]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146) ~[surefire-testng-2.19.jar:2.19]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:286) ~[surefire-booter-2.19.jar:2.19]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:240) ~[surefire-booter-2.19.jar:2.19]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121) ~[surefire-booter-2.19.jar:2.19]
INFO  2016-10-13 17:33:00,287 [main] com.consol.citrus.Citrus: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO  2016-10-13 17:33:00,287 [main] com.consol.citrus.Citrus:
INFO  2016-10-13 17:33:00,476 [main] com.consol.citrus.Citrus:
INFO  2016-10-13 17:33:00,476 [main] com.consol.citrus.Citrus: -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a dynamic endpoint in the send operation which creates the endpoint on the fly. Unfortunately this mechanism does not support secured http at the moment.

Instead you should add a http client endpoint component to the Citrus configuration and use this static endpoint in your send operation by reference.

You can follow this sample project: https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples/tree/master/sample-https

Comment: What about citrus.jks file? Does it work with my https endpoint if I configure http client endpoint component in citrus context?

Comment: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method send()
  location: class com.consol.citrus.dsl.builder.HttpClientActionBuilder
 cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method receive()
  location: class com.consol.citrus.dsl.builder.HttpClientActionBuilder

Comment: The JKS file is the Java Key store that holds the certificates for secure handshake. You may want to create your own keystore that holds the required certificates of your domain, citrus.jks is just a sample.